# Traverse HTML snippet from a click to get the contents of a span

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML (that is repeated many times) and want to get the contents of the span immediately before the href that I click.

```
<p class="listitem">
  <img src="./1.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50"/>
  <span class="votecount">22</span> Votes
  <span class="name">Richard Wilde</span>
  <a href="ViewEntry.aspx?Id=1019">View Entry</a>
  <div id="id-1"><a href="#" rel="vote-1019" >...</a></div>
</p>
```

I also have the following jquery, I am trying to populate count with 22 but can't seem to figure this one out.

```
$("a[rel^='vote']").click(function () {
  var id = ($(this).attr("rel")).replace("vote-", "");
  $(this).unbind("click");
  var count= $(this).parent("div").parent(".listitem").children(".votecount");
  return false;
});
```

*edit* sorry, even I add .text() on end I get NULL, I think the traversing is not quite right.

Comment: See my edited answer. Copied your code and got it working, but the solution doesn't make a lot of sense....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have a `div` inside `p` element. A `div` is a structural element whereas `p`is for containing text so it doesn't really make sense. Your browser (or at least Chrome for me) is rewriting your HTML to be as follows:

```
<p class="listitem">
   <img src="./1.jpg" alt="" width="50" height="50"/>
   <span class="votecount">22</span> Votes
   <span class="name">Richard Wilde</span>
   <a href="ViewEntry.aspx?Id=1019">View Entry</a>
</p>
<div id="id-1"><a href="#" rel="vote-1019" >...</a></div>
<p></p>
```

As you can see `p.listitem` is no longer the parent of the vote link. If you change `p.listitem` to be `div.listitem` then your code, with the addition of `.text()` works as expected.

I've added the code to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uxabuf/edit) to demonstrate.

Comment: Simple when you know how! Thanks, failed to spot the problems of having divs inside of P's

Comment: That makes sense. How many programmers does it take to change a light-bulb again? Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the [`text` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('.votecount').text()
```

Comment: please make sure you've copied your HTML exactly. If there's a typo it could mess up the rendering

Answer (score 1):

Copied your code, and got it working with this:

```
var count = $(this).parents().find(".votecount").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count= $(this).parent("div").parent(".listitem").children(".votecount");
```

should be

```
var count= $(this).parent("div").parent(".listitem").children(".votecount").text();
```